# Mass data store with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

We need management 10,000 GPS devices, each GPS device upload a GPS data every 30 seconds, these data need to store in the database (SQL Server 2005).

Each GPS device daily data quantity is: 24 * 60 * 2 = 2,880 10 000

10,000 GPS devices daily data quantity is: 10000 * 2880 = 28,800,000

Each GPS data approximately 160Byte, the amount of data per day is: 28,800,000 * 160 = 4.29GB

We need hold at least 3 months of GPS data in the database,

My question is:

1, whether SQL Server 2005 can support such a large amount of data store?

2, How to plan data table? (all GPS data storage in one table? Daily table? Each GPS device with a GPS data table?)

---

The GPS data:

```
GPSID varchar(21),
RecvTime datetime,
GPSTime datetime,
IsValid bit,
IsNavi bit,
Lng float,
Lat float,
Alt float,
Spd smallint,
Head smallint,
PulseValue bigint,
Oil float,
TSW1 bigint,
TSW1Mask bigint,
TSW2 bigint,
TSW2Mask,
BSW bigint,
StateText varchar(200),
PosText varchar(200),
UploadType tinyint
```

---

I tend to use partition table. However, how to set the boundaries?

Comment: All data stored in one table(table name: GPSTracks), for data storage, query, management is very convenient. But the problem is the amount of data in this table is too huge! Table partition appears to be a good idea, but if the border demarcation is a difficult problem.

Comment: Every day a table (table name: GPSTrack_20100617), can reduce the amount of GPS data, but still very large (4.29GB), data query will still be slow, more importantly, when faced cross-day query will be very painful .

Comment: Each GPS device with a GPS data table(table name: GPSTrack_1531332567, "1531332567" is a GPS ID), Can solve the data quantity problem and queries very fast, but there is a crucial question: write speed is too slow (because we need insert data to different table. In addition, also need to check the destination table exists).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, SQL Server 2005 can hold that amount of data.

To be able to answer the last question we would really need to know how you were going to use the data. For instance, if you wanted to do queries on all of the data, putting it in daily tables would be a problem. You also have the problem of how would you handle the daily switch of tables?

I would initially be thinking about keeping the data in a single table that uses table partitioning and putting the historical partitions into filegroups that sit on fast disk for reads. This will make querying the data faster.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. whether SQL Server 2005 can support such a large amount of data store?

Yes, Sql Server has been shown to be able to store peta bytes of information.

> 2, How to plan data table? (all GPS
>   data storage in one table? Daily
>   table? Each GPS device with a GPS data
>   table?)

There is no need to separate the data across table.  That will make data retrieval much more cumbersome in the future.  You want to look at [table partitioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146(SQL.90).aspx).

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/datacenter/?p=139

Comment: The table partition is a perfect solution for Insert, Query, Backup and so on. 
However, the amount of data per day is already very big,
how to set the boundary of partition function, a partition each day?

Comment: I would decide your boundaries on the data inload and outload process, e.g. whether it is loaded and aged daily or weekly.